# Angular text is not spacing out rows

Tags: angular, bootstrap-5

Im a new Angular user.

My Angular App has a section where the rows of text are not being spaced out with rows
Id like it to essentially form a list like this

-ingredient
-ingredient
-ingredient

but instead its doing this
[image]

heres the code
[image]

I was trying to figure out a way to increase the height of the container but wasnt having much luck

I tried playing around with some of the bootstrap with no luck

Comment: So you still want them in the same line but you need more of the vertical spacing?

Comment: I was wondering if vertical spacing could be an issue but I want them to be listed essentially on on top of the other id that makes sense. thanks!

Comment: In this case, move the `*ngFor` to the `div` containing the `col` class. i.e., `<div class="col-xs-12">` becomes `<div class="col-xs-12" *ngFor="let ingredient of recipe.ingredients">`.

Comment: You're probably looking for [`white-space: pre-wrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the line height, it's very simple.
there's bootstrap classes can adjust text line height. there's the classes:

```html
<p class="lh-1">This is a long paragraph written to show how the line-height of an element is affected by our utilities. Classes are applied to the element itself or sometimes the parent element. These classes can be customized as needed with our utility API.</p>
<p class="lh-sm">This is a long paragraph written to show how the line-height of an element is affected by our utilities. Classes are applied to the element itself or sometimes the parent element. These classes can be customized as needed with our utility API.</p>
<p class="lh-base">This is a long paragraph written to show how the line-height of an element is affected by our utilities. Classes are applied to the element itself or sometimes the parent element. These classes can be customized as needed with our utility API.</p>
<p class="lh-lg">This is a long paragraph written to show how the line-height of an element is affected by our utilities. Classes are applied to the element itself or sometimes the parent element. These classes can be customized as needed with our utility API.</p>
```